# Jquery Hide() and Show() Not Working -- Extremely Frustated

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have some HTML like this

```
<div id="topContainer">
 <div id="level1" style="display:none;"> </div>
 <div id="level2" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

I can retrieve level1 and level2, calling show() and hide() on them successfully. However, having style="display:none;" and then calling jQuery("#topContainer").show() does nada. :(

What could possibly be wrong?

JS Below

```
//LOGIC HERE THAT SHOWS LEVEL1 and LEVEL2 based on business logic

//If neither div is shown (got a variable set to false, it set to true each time
//the business logic shows the div
//if variable is still false, then the below line runs
jQuery("#topContainer").hide()
```

Updated with as much code as I can.

Comment: define **nada**. also, which element(s) have `style="display:none;"? is this in your CSS? please clarify your question.

Comment: I am getting no error. I'm just seeing the top level div still being displayed. I've called hide and it's still there. :(

Comment: style="display:none" is in the HTML markup.

Comment: Nada = the element that should be hidden NOT hidden. ;) level1 and level2 have display:none set in HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) on a parent doesn't affect the children, if they're hidden they stay hidden...they're handled independently.

However, you can call [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) on the children as well if needed, for example:

```
jQuery("#topContainer").show().children().show();
```

Comment: I am trying to hide a parent along with all its children.

Comment: @bobber205 - In that case just `jQuery("#topContainer").hide()` will work...make sure you're calling this inside a `document.ready` handler if doing it on page load, like this: `$(function() { jQuery("#topContainer").hide(); });`

Comment: The code that is calling hide is in the *same* function as the shows() to its children. Literally right next to each other. It is in a ready() function too. :)

Comment: @bobber205 - Are you getting an error?  Also *post your code*, always.

Comment: I don't think company policy allows me to post it just with a straight copy and paste job.

Comment: @bobber205 - "Hi, there's something wrong with my car"...how is the mechanic to correctly diagnose the issue without *seeing* the car?

Comment: @bobber205 : you can always manipulate your work, can't you? a dummy page will not expose of anything sensitive to your work at all.

Comment: That would require alot of effort (nowhere to host atm). I think I've explained the problem pretty well in my simple example above.

Comment: I have several divs inside one one big div. I am using JS to determine what content goes in each of these divs. If no content is ever added to any of these divs, I want to make sure that the container div is also hidden. So I have it shown by default and trying to hide it if I never add content to it.

Comment: @bobber205 - You're **very** abstractly describing a problem and showing us *zero* code to go along with it...we need to see your code to help.

Comment: @bobber205 - just as a sanity test replace `jQuery("#topContainer").hide()` with `alert(jQuery("#topContainer").length)`, what do you get?

Comment: 1. I am doing if (topContainer.length) before any of the above runs. I've also seen the object in Firebug and it's a valid object.

Comment: I've tried getting rid of the inner divs and just calling topContainer.hide() and it works.

Comment: @bobber205 - are you sure all your tags are closed validly?

Comment: Ah google search i love you, thanks for this answer. It worked and I up voted as well as it helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the logic to hide the `#topContainer` is causing the problems. I set up a demo here to display the utility of the [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector; but in order for an element to be considered empty, it can not even contain even a single space (text node).

With the HTML you provided. I've set up a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/nqnmp/)... add content in the div then re-run the script, and you can see the difference.

```
var container = $('#topContainer'),
    divs = container.find('div'),
    empty = divs.filter(':empty');

if (divs.length == empty.length) {
    // hide container!
    $('#topContainer').hide();
    alert('hidden!');
} else {
    // don't do anything
    alert("don't hide!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `$("#topContainer").css("display", "block");` work?

Does `$("#topContainer").css("background", "red");` work?

Have you poked around with Firebug or something else that can show the actual DOM properties before and after, along with the rule cascade.

My suspicion would be that `#topContainer` is getting `display` set via something else, or another there is another div with #topContainer` further down the page (which would be invalid HTML).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was different, situation a little different though

The script was placed before the DOM created the element to hide.

I change the script to the "after page load"

```
$(function(){
   // logic
});
```